# How to update 0ad?

Tags: updates, games

I have a game called 0ad installed through apt-get, its listed in the software center too. My game version is Alpha 16, but the latest is Alpha 17.

Their website doesn't show how to update the game. How do I update it?

I tried apt-get install, but it won't update.

```
sudo apt-get install 0ad
```

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/355273/how-do-i-install-0-a-d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wfg/0ad
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install 0ad
```